# How to read a Mulesoft 4 flow response in java

Tags: java, mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-component

I have a java connector that access the registry and triggers a flow using Java SDK. The result of the flow execution is a JSON payload. The reason I am doing this is because the requirement is to invoke a flow, get the response back, extract the attributes and use them to query another API using the pollingsource strategy as a source adding the queryparameters found in the resulting payload from the flow invocation.

The response payload is an object:

```
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider@2e58ddfc
```

Would you have any idea on how to parse it to a JSON or any other way of accessing the values?

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should provide more clarity into what are you trying to achieve, what is the original problem you are trying to resolve. For what you need to access the object in Java instead of using Mule 4 features? Depending on that the answer could be different.